# Why does this statement have unintentional side-effects?

Tags: c, linux, bash, debugging

I'm using a statement that has side-effect but I can't understand why. If I use this statement then the rest is my program breaks.

`token3 = strtok(pathValue, ":");`

The variables `token3` and `pathvalue` are not used anywhere else so there should not be side-effect. But if I include them then I get runtime error when trying to run other part of the program. What have I done wrong? The entire program is a linux program that is my own shell working similar to bash and the tokenizing is to find if less is installed on the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This page of the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv) for `getenv()` is clue-rich:

> The string pointed to by the return value of `getenv()` may be statically allocated, and can be modified by a subsequent call to `getenv()`, `putenv(3)`, `setenv(3)`, or `unsetenv(3)`.

So it's probably not a good idea to go around and modifying this, which `strtok()` will do. Try copying the string first.

The lesson is: *always* be wary when C functions return pointers in general, and strings in particular. Who owns the memory being pointed at?

Comment: Cool, it worked with the change just copying the string.